# LSI 9211-8i mismatch between logical and physical units

Tags: ssd, raid

I have an LSI 9211-8i.  On the first connector I have 2 SSDs; on the 2nd I have 4 2Tb disks.

Now the odd part is that the physical and unit mappings don't match:

```
% sas2ircu 0 display 
Initiator at ID #0

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 0
  SAS Address                             : 4433221-1-0300-0000
  State                                   : Ready (RDY)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 488386/1000215215
  Manufacturer                            : ATA     
  Model Number                            : Crucial_CT512MX1
....
Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 1
  SAS Address                             : 4433221-1-0200-0000
  State                                   : Ready (RDY)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 488386/1000215215
  Manufacturer                            : ATA     
  Model Number                            : Crucial_CT512MX1
```

So we can see the two SSDs are showing up as slots 0 and 1.

But:

```
 $sas2flash -c 0 -o -testlsall | grep Phy
        Phy 0: Link Down
        Phy 1: Link Down
        Phy 2: 6.0 Gbps
        Phy 3: 6.0 Gbps
....
```

So we can see the two SSDs are actually plugged into physical channels 2 and 3 (which matches the cabling).

How is this mapping determined?  How can I make the controller map 1-1.

FWIW, it's running 19IR firmware but I don't have any raid devices created.  Would I be better flashing to IT?

Answer (score 0):

did u update the firmware to P19?

This can happen when updating the firmware and overriding the manufacturer data.
Updates with sas2flash.efi -o -e -6 will preserve the manufacturing data.

Best bet would be to use the oem fiemare for the card, eg Super Micro.

Comment: This is more a comment then a full fledged 'this will always solve it for you!' answer.